# wpf datagrid to wpf datagrid value display

Tags: c#, wpf

i'm new in wpf c#,i want to know  how to display when we selected a row in datagrid1,that values pass to another datagrid of another form,please help me to solve.
when am clicked a datagrid row means it want to show in next window's datagrid with a progressbar and a button
please help me to solve this code.

```
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Gender}" Value="M">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Gender}" Value="F">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Lime"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Patient ID}" Header="Patient ID" Width="120" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Patient Name}" Header="Patient Name" Width="150" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Gender}" Header="Gender" Width="100" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Study Date Time}" Header="Study Date &amp;Time" Width="150" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Modality}" Header="Modality" Width="150" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Study Name}" Header="Study Name" Width="150" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Ref Physicion}" Header="Ref Physician" Width="150" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Instances}" Header="Instances" Width="150" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Clinical History}" Header="Clinical History" Width="150" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Status}" Header="Status" Width="100" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <!--<DataGrid Name="fo" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectedItem="key" Grid.Row="1">-->
            <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu x:Name="CMenu">
                    <MenuItem Name="Send" Header="Send" Click="Send_Click"/>
                    <MenuItem Name="check" Header="Check Report in Server"/>
                    <MenuItem Name="Delete" Header="Delete"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
            </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <!--</DataGrid>-->
    </DataGrid>
    <Canvas Height="30" Name="canvas4" Margin="1,549,-1,150">
        <Label Canvas.Left="14" Canvas.Top="0" Content="SeriesDetails:" Height="28" Name="label4" FontFamily="Vijaya" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" />
    </Canvas>
    <Canvas Name="canvas5" Margin="0,698,-1,0">
        <Label Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="1" Content="Welcome Team" Height="28" Name="label5" FontFamily="Vijaya" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="24" />
        <Label Content="Optics Image Server" Height="28" Name="label6" Canvas.Left="1153" Canvas.Top="1" FontFamily="Vijaya" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" Width="164" />
        <ProgressBar Canvas.Left="145" Canvas.Top="6" Height="19" Name="progressBar1" Width="133" Visibility="Visible" />
    </Canvas>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dataGrid2" Width="1344" Margin="2,579,-2,31">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Series No" Width="450" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Series Description" Width="450" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ins" Width="250" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Try this in google "wpf datagrid selected item binding".

Comment: i'm new in wpf,can u help me

Comment: I already did, but if you can't understand that, then sorry, I can't help you anymore. =(

Comment: give any clue to do plz

Comment: [Clue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13755507/1997232), [Clue](http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html)

Comment: pease help me to solve