# Keep SelectedItem in Focus on ColumnSort WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

What I am attempting to do is the keep the `DataGrid.SelectedItem` in focus when the user sorts the column by click on the header at the top of the `DataGrid`. At the moment I am calling my own method on the click of the `DataGrid` column header;

```
    private void headerClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedCompany = dataGrid.SelectedItem as CompanyModel;
        var columnHeader = sender as DataGridColumnHeader;
        if (columnHeader != null)
        {
            SetSelectedCompany(Convert.ToInt32(selectedCompany.CompanyID));
        }
    }
```

This calls **SetSelectedCompany**

```
    private void SetSelectedCompany(int companyID)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var item in dataGrid.Items.OfType<CompanyModel>())
            {
                if (item.CompanyID == companyID.ToString())// suppose iterRow.Row.ItemArray[0] is ID column in yourDataGrid
                {
                    dataGrid.SelectedItem = item;
                    dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(dataGrid.SelectedItem);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var hEs = new HandleExceptionService();
            hEs.HandleException(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

This method does work when I call it from other places in my UI, however it does not work on the click of the `DataGrid` column header. Is this due to the `SetSelectedCompany` method being called, and THEN the `DataGrid` is filtered? How can I get round this so `SetSelectedCompany` is the last method called on the filter process?

Answer (score 0):

Try to handle `ColumnHeader` `click`. ColumnHeader is just a `Button`:

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid">
   <DataGrid.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
         <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="columnHeader_Click" />
      </Style>
   </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>

private void columnHeader_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var columnHeader = sender as DataGridColumnHeader;
   if (columnHeader != null)
   {
      SetSelectedCompany(11);     
   }
}
```

Comment: I've tried it without this method and it doesn't automatically keep focus when the `DataGrid` is sorted.

Comment: @CBreeze you mean that after data is loaded to DataGrid, then an user selects item, then click at the header column to sort by the column and the SelectedItem is reset?

Comment: The `SelectedItem` is kept but it is not Scrolled into view.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an easy way of sorting databound rows while maintaining a user selected row's focus but if you could provide some more info on why focus is required after sorting(it's not conventional UI behaviour) then maybe we can figure out a different way to skin a cat.

Try binding the user's selected row to actual data, like a record ID or something. Then on your sort method set focus to the row where ID = {binded-value}

[WPF Binding SelectedItem in DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755507/wpf-binding-selecteditem-in-datagrid)