# How to bind to two properties in different sources?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'd like to have a combobox whose ItemsSource is fed from a posteViewSource and it's SelectedItem to be bound to the idPoste field of the table that is linked to superviseurViewSource.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:StagesBDDataSet x:Key="stagesBDDataSet"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="superviseurViewSource" Source="{Binding Superviseur, Source={StaticResource stagesBDDataSet}}"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="posteViewSource" Source="{Binding Poste, Source={StaticResource stagesBDDataSet}}"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Here's my combobox definition:

```
        <ComboBox x:Name="idPosteComboBox" DataContext="{StaticResource posteViewSource}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Height="23" Width="120" DisplayMemberPath="idPoste" />
```

The combobox is in a grid whose DataContext is set to : {StaticResource superviseurViewSource}. The binding with the items works perfectly, but I don't know if it's possible to have another DataContext for the SelectedItem property. Any hints would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Does not makes sense, binding `SelectedItem` to an item's `idPoste` -> yes, binding it to a `CollectionViewSource` -> no, on what item in this collection it would be bound to ?

Comment: That would be idPoste also. The combobox is filled with the rows of the Poste table (linked to the collectionviewsource mentionned above), that works fine. Now what I want is to bind the selecteditem in that combobox with the field idPoste in the current row of the Superviseur table's collectionviewsource. It's a bit challenging to me to explain it, I hope this helps.

Comment: Well then you have to track currently selected item in this table, you are probably using a data grid or something : http://stackoverflow.com/a/13755582/361899 . Once you have that you can bind to a property somewhere else in a control like `<ComboBox DataContext="{StaticResource resource1}" Content="{Binding TextInResource1}" Tooltip="{Binding ElementName=resource2, Path=Something}" />`

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a binding for ItemSource and another binding for SelectedItem, so you can write:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="idPosteComboBox"
   DataContext="{StaticResource posteViewSource}" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
   SelectedItem="{Binding ---another binding---}"
   IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
   Height="23" Width="120" DisplayMemberPath="idPoste" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I tried it, but no luck. Is this ok for the binding of SelectedItem?

SelectedItem="{Binding Source=superviseurViewSource, Path=idPoste, Mode=TwoWay}"