# C# WPF KeyDown highlight + selected last row in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, select, datagrid, highlight

I'm working on application where user can add products to a datagrid, with simple informations like product name and price, and after that 
I would like to for example press F4 key on my keyboard and I would like to focus on last item in datagrid, that means select it and HIGHLIGHT that item!

So guys how could I achieve that, I've tried few solutions like setting selected index to my datagrid and smth like that, but it is not working

Thanks guys,
Cheers

Comment: Do you have any sample code?  What code did you use to set the selected index?  What part of your attempt didn't work?  Please write a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example to go with your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Programmatically highlighting a row or cell in a `DataGrid` is a bit more complicated than just setting the `SelectedIndex` or `SelectedItem` property.

It is however possible to select and focus a row in code and get the same behaviour as when using the mouse by accessing the visual user interface elements of the `DataGrid` control and calling the `UIElement.Focus()` method on a particular `DataGridCell` object as described in the following blog post.

**How to programmatically select and focus a row or cell in a DataGrid in WPF:** https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/11/08/how-to-programmatically-select-and-focus-a-row-or-cell-in-a-datagrid-in-wpf/

Here is an example:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.PreviewKeyDown += (s, e) => 
        {
            if(e.Key == Key.F4)
                SelectRowByIndex(dataGridProducts, dataGridProducts.Items.Count - 1);
        };

        //populate DataGrid etc...
    }

    private static void SelectRowByIndex(DataGrid dataGrid, int rowIndex)
    {
        if (!dataGrid.SelectionUnit.Equals(DataGridSelectionUnit.FullRow))
            throw new ArgumentException("The SelectionUnit of the DataGrid must be set to FullRow.");

        if (rowIndex < 0 || rowIndex > (dataGrid.Items.Count - 1))
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("{0} is an invalid row index.", rowIndex));

        dataGrid.SelectedItems.Clear();
        object item = dataGrid.Items[rowIndex];
        dataGrid.SelectedItem = item;

        DataGridRow row = dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(rowIndex) as DataGridRow;
        if (row == null)
        {
            /* bring the data item (Product object) into view
             * in case it has been virtualized away */
            dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(item);
            row = dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(rowIndex) as DataGridRow;
        }
        if (row != null)
        {
            DataGridCell cell = GetCell(dataGrid, row, 0);
            if (cell != null)
                cell.Focus();
        }
    }

    private static DataGridCell GetCell(DataGrid dataGrid, DataGridRow rowContainer, int column)
    {
        if (rowContainer != null)
        {
            System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridCellsPresenter presenter 
                = FindVisualChild<System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridCellsPresenter>(rowContainer);
            if (presenter == null)
            {
                /* if the row has been virtualized away, call its ApplyTemplate() method 
                 * to build its visual tree in order for the DataGridCellsPresenter
                 * and the DataGridCells to be created */
                rowContainer.ApplyTemplate();
                presenter = FindVisualChild<System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridCellsPresenter>(rowContainer);
            }
            if (presenter != null)
            {
                DataGridCell cell = presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column) as DataGridCell;
                if (cell == null)
                {
                    /* bring the column into view
                     * in case it has been virtualized away */
                    dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(rowContainer, dataGrid.Columns[column]);
                    cell = presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column) as DataGridCell;
                }
                return cell;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static T FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject obj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
                return (T)child;
            else
            {
                T childOfChild = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
                if (childOfChild != null)
                    return childOfChild;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you God of this game? You are awesome man! thanks a lot! how come you know all these stuffs?

Comment: Experience is king :)

Comment: I will vote up whatever you want man! Just could you sometimes write comments in your code (even if you write it before posting a code) for example  you could write comments above code line i.e why you did this and why you did that, its much more easy to understand your code than! And one more time THANK YOU A LOT! :)

Comment: I did, didn't I?

Comment: Yes you did it here sir! I am speaking more about previous question, you also posted awesome answer! it was about removing item from observable collection etc, and there you offered perfect solution but I stuggled with understanding it little bit but after while it was OK! I'm just speaking that because It is easy to see that you are really experienced person so every word  from you is very helpful for all of us ( young programmers with not so much experience) whatever. Once again thanks a lot!!

Comment: It's a very complicated but complete solution. Some remarks, if dataGridProducts.Items.Count == 0, it generates an exception because index = -1. Furthermore, it doesn't works for me perhaps because I'm using framework 4.0 for Windows XP compatibility.

Comment: Update, an exception is raised with dataGrid.SelectedItems.Clear() when DataGrid SelectionMode="Single". In this case, just delete the dataGrid.SelectedItems.Clear();  line. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an InputBinding to recognize the pressed F4 Key.

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="F4"
                Command="{Binding SelectLastItemCommand}" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

You can have a look here for how to select the item: [WPF Binding SelectedItem in DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755507/wpf-binding-selecteditem-in-datagrid)

Answer (score 0):

Where does your problem lie? With handling the button event or highlighting the row? It seems like its the latter, so have a look at this:
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/773382/Row-Highlighting-in-WPF-Grids